# create a view from a table with auto incremental column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view from table that does not have any unique or primary key. I tried to make use of the following `sql statment` but it giving an error

```
  #let presume the table name is foo
  SELECT rownum, * from (SELECT * from foo)

  #error
  #ORA-00936: missing expression
  #00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Is there I am missing anything or need to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would run if you provided an alias

```
select rownum,
       a.*
  from (select *
          from foo) a
```

Of course, as written, you could simplify the query to just

```
select rownum,
       foo.*
  from foo
```

but I'm assuming there is something else going on in your subquery that makes it reasonable to use a subquery in the first place.

Taking a step back, though, I'm not sure that your query would do what you want even if you got it to work.  Using `rownum` to assign a pseudo-key is unlikely to be very helpful.  Unless your subquery had an `order by` clause that produced a unique order and you can guarantee that you would never insert a row that sorts earlier than some existing row, which seems very unlikely, the `rownum` that is assigned to a particular row may change from run to run of your query.  A "key" that doesn't uniquely and persistently identify a row of data is a pretty pointless thing.  Even if you can guarantee those things, though, you can't use the `rownum` for updates and if you try to add predicates to queries against the view, you likely won't get the results you want.

Comment: A bit more explanation.  Oracle does not require an alias for `select *`.  However, if you include other columns in the `select`, *then* it needs an alias.  A bit confusing, unless you are in the habit of always using table aliases (which I recommend).